# using inject for long traversal in gremlin when dealing with optional fields

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm building a long traversal to add hundreds of vertices in one query. I saw from the official website that the recommended way to do it is to inject the object list and add vertices there: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#long-traversals

However in my case there's a lot of objects that have optional fields, take the example in the official doc, there might be someone who doesn't have the 'age' property, or 'name' property, I can use choose to do something like this:

```
g.inject().unfold().as('a').addV().choose(select('a').select('age'), property('age', select('a').select('age')))
```

but the choose step in Neptune is not optimized and this adds too much latency for the query, are there any other solutions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already answered on the gremlin-users mailing list, but to close the loop, here it is again:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> 
gremlin> data = [["name": "Huimin Yang"],
                 ["name": "Daniel Kuppitz", "age": 37]]
==>[name:Huimin Yang]
==>[name:Daniel Kuppitz,age:37]
gremlin> 
gremlin> g.inject(data).unfold().as("m").
           addV("person").as("v").
           select("m").unfold().as("kv").
           select("v").
             property(select("kv").by(keys), select("kv").by(values)).iterate()
gremlin> 
gremlin> g.V().valueMap()
==>[name:[Huimin Yang]]
==>[name:[Daniel Kuppitz],age:[37]]
```

Comment: Indeed this is faster than using choose. Thanks for the awesome solution!